# web3.py web3.isConnected() returns false always

Tags: web3.py

I am trying an tutorial on web3.py

so i created a profile in infura and used its project id.But it shows false always when i try  web3.isConnected()

```
PS C:\Users\HP> python
    Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from web3 import Web3
    >>> infura_url = "mainnet.infura.io/v3/******************************"
    >>> web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
    >>> web3.isConnected()
    False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify how you're connecting to your endpoint in the path itself. If you want to use HTTP(S), prefix the endpoint appropriately.

```
>>> infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<my_API_ID>"
>>> w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
>>> w3.isConnected()
True
```

See the docs for more details on using HTTP(S), IPC, or websockets -> [Choosing How to Connect to Your Node](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html?highlight=isconnected#choosing-how-to-connect-to-your-node).